# Валидация полей с ajax запросом

Tags: c#, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Есть страница в приложении asp.net mvc. Использую валидацию с помощью dataannotation на модели. И использую библиотеки `@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")`
Для того что бы текст ошибок мгновенно на клиенте отрабатывал. И даже если я например нажму на кнопку отправить, вылезут все сообщения по невалидным полям и запрос не отправится. Но есть у меня поле с типом hidden в которое я записываю value с помощью jquery. Для него почему то валидация не работает. Не понимаю в чём разница поле такое же только hidden. Вот пример поля для которого работает и для которого не работает.

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, "Модель")
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "txtModelName", @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.CarModel.ModelName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <br />
                        @Html.LabelFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, "Изображение Автомобиля", new { @style = "padding-right: 50px" })
                        @Html.EditorFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "hidden", @id = "image" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(i => i.Equipment.Picture, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        <br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Для поля модель, всё отрабатывает нормально например поле модель не заполнено, нажимаю кнопку отправить, вылетает ошибка. Если я не заполнил с помощью js значение поля Изображение автомобиля и нажимаю отправить, ошибка не вылетает. В чём разница подскажите пожалуйста? И как это можно исправить?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8466643/5752652

Answer (score 1):

Для того что бы включить валидацию скрытых полей можно использовать следующий код:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('form').validate().settings.ignore = [];
});
```